# Convert text file to list of tuples

Tags: python, string, file, tuples

I am having trouble converting a text file in to a list of tuples. The text file will be in the following format and the file is named data.txt

Evans Lee Comedian 25,000
Smith Will Actor 50,000
Mack Lee Comedian 30,000

I have managed to partially achieve my aim by using the following code

```
load_file = open("data.txt", "r")
data = infile.read()
load_file.close()
data = tuple(item for item in data.split(' ') if item.strip())
print (data)
```

However this does not achieve what i wanted it to, it produces the following output

```
('Evans', 'Lee', 'Comedian', '25,000\nSmith', 'Will', 'Actor', '50,000\nMack', 'Lee', 'Comedian', '30,000')
```

This is just one big long tuple with the newline character included, is there a way I can make it so that each line in the data.txt file is it's own tuple, giving me a list of tuples and get rid of the newline character?

Comment: Just change the '  ' inside data.split() by \n

Answer (score 5):

If you `read()` the entire file into one big string, you have to `splitlines()` first:

```
data = [tuple(line.split()) for line in data.splitlines()]
```

Better: Don't read the file as one big string but iterate lines in the file directly:

```
with open("data.txt") as load_file:
    data = [tuple(line.split()) for line in load_file]
```

Still better: Use `csv` to read the data; this will also allow you to e.g. put names or job titles that contain spaces into quotes:

```
import csv
with open("data.txt") as load_file:
    reader = csv.reader(load_file, delimiter=" ")
    data = [tuple(row) for row in reader]
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. `infile.read()` gives you the entire file as a string, which includes newline characters (`\n`). You could use `.readlines()` instead.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    return tuple(tuple(line.split()) for line in lines)
```

This should give

```
(
  ("Evans", "Lee", "Comedian", "25,000"),
  ("Smith", "Will", "Actor", "50,000"),
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `readlines()`, which reads each line from the input file into a separate item in a list:

```py
load_file = open("data.txt", "r")
raw = infile.readlines()
data = [line.strip() for line in raw]
load_file.close()
print (data)
```

Note this will strip all whitespace from the ends of each line, not just your newline. That's probably OK, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how to parse your file.
In general, files are comma separated values, where we have a single character to split the fields https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values
Or we have a file where columns have a fixed length https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat-file_database

In your case, I would use a regular expression to parse your line.

Try this:

```
import re

with open("data.txt", "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        groups = re.search("^(.+) (\d.*)", line)
        name = groups.group(1)
        value = groups.group(2)
        print("Name: %s Value:%s" % (name, value))
```